# Doctype tag preventing menu to work properly only in IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, menu, compatibility, doctype

I got a sidebar menu from DynamicDrive. I changed it a bit so that can be used from right to left. It works perfectly in all browsers except IE7. After loads of debugging I found out that when I remove the `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">` tag it all works but it doesn't function properly with the doctype tag. What happens is that the sub menus jump to the left of the screen where they should be in the LTR (English) version.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
/*Credits: Dynamic Drive CSS Library */
/*URL: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/ */

.sidebarmenu ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font: bold 13px Verdana;
width: 180px; /* Main Menu Item widths */
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.sidebarmenu ul li{
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
}

/* Top level menu links style */
.sidebarmenu ul li a{
display: block;
overflow: hidden; /*force hasLayout in IE7 */
color: #282828;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 6px;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

}

.sidebarmenu ul li a:link, .sidebarmenu ul li a:visited, .sidebarmenu ul li a:active{
background-color: #EAE8E8;/*#012D58; /*background of tabs (default state)*/
}

.sidebarmenu ul li a:visited{
color: #282828;
}

.sidebarmenu ul li a:hover{
background-color: white;
}

/*Sub level menu items */
.sidebarmenu ul li ul{
position: absolute;
right:170px; /*Only for farsi*/
width: 170px; /*Sub Menu Items width */
top: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}

.sidebarmenu ul li ul li{
    z-index:10;
}

.sidebarmenu a.subfolderstyle{
/*background: url(/html/portlet/ext/sitemap_1/right.gif) no-repeat 97% 50%;*/
}


/* Holly Hack for IE \*/
* html .sidebarmenu ul li { float: left; height: 1%; }
* html .sidebarmenu ul li a { height: 1%; }
/* End */

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

//Nested Side Bar Menu (Mar 20th, 09)
//By Dynamic Drive: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/
if(window.opera){
    loadcssfile("opera.css");
}

function loadcssfile(filename){
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }

var menuids=["sidebarmenu1"] //Enter id(s) of each Side Bar Menu's main UL, separated by commas

function initsidebarmenu(){
for (var i=0; i<menuids.length; i++){
  var ultags=document.getElementById(menuids[i]).getElementsByTagName("ul")
    for (var t=0; t<ultags.length; t++){
    ultags[t].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className+=" subfolderstyle"
  if (ultags[t].parentNode.parentNode.id==menuids[i]) //if this is a first level submenu
   ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t].parentNode.offsetWidth+"px" //dynamically position first level submenus to be width of main menu item
  else //else if this is a sub level submenu (ul)
    ultags[t].style.left=ultags[t-1].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].offsetWidth+"px" //position menu to the right of menu item that activated it
    ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseover=function(){
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="block"
    }
    ultags[t].parentNode.onmouseout=function(){
    this.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style.display="none"
    }
    }
  for (var t=ultags.length-1; t>-1; t--){ //loop through all sub menus again, and use "display:none" to hide menus (to prevent possible page scrollbars
  ultags[t].style.visibility="visible"
  ultags[t].style.display="none"
  }
  }
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", initsidebarmenu, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", initsidebarmenu)

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidebarmenu">
<ul id="sidebarmenu1">
<li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Folder 1</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Folder 2</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Folder 2.1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried other a strict doctype?

Comment: Unfortunately It's quite hard for me to do that cos the whole site (which is based on Liferay) is quite huge and I don't know what kind of effect that would have on the rest of the site. But I found something which seems to be the solution. It worked. I added a width of 170px for the ul li. It seems the width was set to something big by default.